# Having trouble building a very simple OpenCV C++ .so library using CMake for use on Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to use CMake to create a .so library that uses OpenCV for use on Android.

I have no prior experience with CMake before this.  I got a couple things working with CMake so far.  I successfully built and ran a simple OpenCV program for windows and I've also created a .so file that doesn't use OpenCV.  I was able to successfully called that .so from a Unity program on Android.  My goal is to create an OpenCV plugin for Unity.  I turned to CMake because I tried making a simple .so in Visual Studios, but my Unity program couldn't find it (though I was able to create a .dll that used OpenCV for a windows Unity program using Visual Studios that worked).

I have both r19c Android NDK and OpenCV 4.5.2 Android SDK on my C drive.

My code file is test.cpp, and it very simply uses some OpenCV elements.  It's as follows:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

extern "C" int get_number()
{
    cv::Mat img(2,2, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(126,0,255));
    cv::Size size = img.size();
    int width = size.width;
    return width;
}
```

I am thinking that my error may be in the CMakeLists.txt file, that I am probably pointing to the wrong OpenCV folders.

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(OpenCV_DIR C:/OpenCVAndroid/sdk/native/jni/abi-arm64-v8a)
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS C:/OpenCVAndroid/sdk/native/jni/include)

project( test )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_library( test SHARED test.cpp )
```

and I'm using a .bat file that has the following lines:

```
rmdir /s /q build
mkdir build
cd build
 
"C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" ^
  -S=C:\Users\m_knu\Desktop\test ^
  -G"MinGW Makefiles" ^
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\r19c\android-ndk-r19c\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake ^
  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\r19c\android-ndk-r19c\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe ^
  -DANDROID_NDK=C:\r19c\android-ndk-r19c ^
  -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-21 ^
  -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a ^
  -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="C:/OpenCVAndroid/sdk/native/jni/abi-armeabi-v7a" ^
 
"C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" --build .

pause
```

all three files are located in the same folder.

When I run the .bat file I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\m_knu\Desktop\test>rmdir /s /q build

C:\Users\m_knu\Desktop\test>mkdir build

C:\Users\m_knu\Desktop\test>cd build

C:\Users\m_knu\Desktop\test\build>"C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe"   -S=C:\Users\m_knu\Desktop\test   -G"MinGW Makefiles"   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release   -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\r19c\android-ndk-r19c\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake   -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\r19c\android-ndk-r19c\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe   -DANDROID_NDK=C:\r19c\android-ndk-r19c   -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-21   -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a   -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="C:/OpenCVAndroid/sdk/native/jni/abi-armeabi-v7a"
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/r19c/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/r19c/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenCV: C:/OpenCVAndroid (found version "4.5.2")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/m_knu/Desktop/test/build

C:\Users\m_knu\Desktop\test\build>"C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" --build .
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libtest.so
CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o: In function `get_number':
C:\Users\m_knu\Desktop\test/test.cpp:5: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)'
C:\Users\m_knu\Desktop\test/test.cpp:9: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libtest.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

C:\Users\m_knu\Desktop\test\build>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As I mentioned earlier, my guess is that I've incorrectly referenced the OpenCV directories, but I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing other things.

Comment: You forgot to **link** with OpenCV. Like `target_link_libraries(test ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: It looks like the correct response to having one's question answered is to "click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in", but I don't see a check mark.  But yes, thank you, you're answer solved it.  Digging into it now I see that OpenCVConfig.cmake sets OpenCV_LIBRARIES.  I at one time had this line but I screwed it up by setting OpenCV_LIBRARIES myself.

Comment: Stack Overflow has both *posts* (question, answer) and *comments*. The former ones are "official" and the later ones are "unofficial". My previous response (and given one too) are *comments*: they cannot be "accepted". The main purpose of comments are clarification requests.

Comment: BTW, it's possible to use easily the C++ API of OpenCV all from Java without having to deal at all with the NDK: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv